# What is the recommended way to build the same code against different sets of dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle

My project `Bar` depends on the library `Foo`. There are different versions of `Foo`, say `foo-v1`, `foo-v2` and `foo-v3`.

I want to build my project against each of those versions separately and produce three separate artifacts, e.g. `bar-with-foo-v1`, `bar-with-foo-v2` and `bar-with-foo-v3`.

What is the recommended way to do such a thing in Gradle?

Comment: I would have program modules if your IDE supports it (akin to maven modules, not sure what that is in gradle). Keep an abstraction of what you need in the main code, and in these modules you can implement the api-specific code (e.g. v1's code in one module, v2's in another). Then you compile the modules, including the core code as a dependency

Comment: You can check customizing dependency resolution behavior in gradle. Might be help  you. I have't trying it.

Comment: Won't these different Foo versions have different interfaces, and wouldn't you have to adjust your code accordingly? I think I'd approach this as different VCS branches if you must keep old libraries around.

Answer (score 0):

You could use propery/profile:

```
gradle -Pversion1 build
```

Configuration:

```
dependencies {
    if (project.hasProperty('version1')) {
        compile "foo-v1"
    } else if (project.hasProperty('version2')) {
        compile "foo-v2"
    } else {
        compile "foo-v3"
    }
...
}
```

Comment: This is not quite what I want. This still produces one artifact per build - I can just choose which. What I want is that all three artifacts are built on every build.